# When shopping for a set of items, find the lowest price set of bundled items

Tags: algorithms

Suppose a store sells items `a, b, ..., z`.

Rather than sell the items à la carte, the store bundles them at seemingly arbitrary prices, e.g.:

```
+-----------+---------------+-------+
| bundle    |     items     | price |
+-----------+---------------+-------+
|         1 | 1 a           |    10 |
|         2 | 1 b           |    10 |
|         3 | 1 a, 1 b      |    15 |
|         4 | 1 a, 1 b, 2 c |     5 |
|         5 | 1 a, 2 c      |    20 |
+-----------+---------------+-------+
```

Given the bundles and a shopping list of items, e.g., `1 a, 2 b, 6 c, etc.`, find the lowest price set of bundles that includes all the shopping list items. It's ok to leave with unwanted items because you can sell them on ebay.

Comment: This is a weighted version of a problem called Minimum Set Cover. Unfortunately it is NP-hard to solve exactly, even without weights ("prices" here), so no one knows of a fast (polynomial-time) algorithm to solve large instances.

Comment: In this particular case it is quite obvious that you should only buy bundle 4. There are NP complete problems where _many_ cases are easy to solve